# Zend Mail not sending any emails

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-mail

So Zend_Mail should be easy, right? Here is my code:

```
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport(new Zend_Mail_Transport_Postmark('e8eeb5e5-bdbf-47cb-bd66-8b7f20d2c08e'));
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom($email);
$mail->addTo($to);
$mail->addBcc($bcc);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBodyHtml($message);
$mail->send();
```

Then why the hell isn't it working (I mean, emails are not sent. Nothing happens. I check my email, but nothing is sent)

I should say, I've set up my server to work with Google Apps. Is that going to cause any problems for this?

Comment: Define "isn't working".

Comment: It is not sending an email.

Comment: What is `Zend_Mail_Transport_Postmark`? How are we supposed to guess?

Comment: I don't know, I copied this off a website that said you should include it!

Comment: @user1083320: this is a community for developers, not for copy-pasters. Contact the original code author for that.

Comment: I also asked a question that has nothing to do with the code: If i change mail setting so Google App servers, would that cause problem with php mail()???

Comment: Look into SMTP if you are going to use Google servers.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know Google isn't bouncing the email? - check that somehow if you can.

Also, it's very common for emails to go to spam when you're still configuring your PHP, so check there (to do with SPF records and your from address).

Finally, verify that `$email`, `$to`, `$bcc`, `$subject` and `$message` are all actually set with a value.